# Can't view ggplot generated pdf in Adobe despite using dev.off() comand

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I'm having trouble opening a pdf created with ggplot. When I attempt to open the file in Adobe I receive an error message stating that I cannot open the file because it is still open in another application. I *am* using dev.off() so I'm not sure why I can't open the pdf...

Here are my graphical parameters and variables:

```
stepheights=c(1.3,  2.6,  3.9,  5.2,  6.6,  7.9,  9.2, 10.5, 11.8, 13.1, 14.4,   15.7, 17.1, 18.4, 19.7, 21.0, 22.3, 23.6, 24.9, 26.2, 27.6, 28.9, 30.2, 31.5, 32.8, 34.1)

  Qs=c(2.0381420, NaN, 2.9921695, NaN, 6.9614420, 109.6719419, 80.7758644, NaN, 7.9477900, 18.3467407, 46.6796869, 117.7829841, 122.2436537, 6.8123483, 26.6823085, 74.5536880, 0.0421594, 92.1911593, 42.8689561, 18.5230607, 23.0842770, 132.5477074, 50.2996339, 3.1371337, NaN,NaN)
```

Both variables are in the data frame VelocityData

```
 #create our graphing parameters using ggplot
downstream_QS<-ggplot(data=VelocityData, aes(x=stepheights, y=Qs))+geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~log(x), fill="red") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=x) +
  labs(x="Distance Downstream (cm)", y="Sediment Transport") +
  ggtitle("Sediment Transport Downstream of a Backward-Facing Step as Calculated from Near-bed Shear Stress") + 
  theme(plot.title=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", size=24), 
        axis.title.y=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", 
                                  size=14), axis.title.x=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", size=14),
        axis.text.y=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", size=10),
        axis.text.x=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", size=10))

pdf(paste('C:/Users/kcpotter/Desktop/Flume/BS Experiments/Step/ADV Qs Profile.pdf'), width=8, height=4)
print(downstream_QS)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Can you delete the file and try again? That doesn't sound like an R related error.

Comment: deleting the file and then using ggsave() fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a small problem with your ggplot code.

For the line:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=x) +
```

you need to use the x variable which is `stepheights`

It should then work.

To save I prefer `ggsave`. The full, working code with both save options is:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create dataframe
 stepheights=c(1.3,  2.6,  3.9,  5.2,  6.6,  7.9,  9.2, 10.5, 11.8, 13.1, 14.4,   15.7, 17.1, 18.4, 19.7, 21.0, 22.3, 23.6, 24.9, 26.2, 27.6, 28.9, 30.2, 31.5, 32.8, 34.1)
 Qs=c(2.0381420, NaN, 2.9921695, NaN, 6.9614420, 109.6719419, 80.7758644, NaN, 7.9477900, 18.3467407, 46.6796869, 117.7829841, 122.2436537, 6.8123483, 26.6823085, 74.5536880, 0.0421594, 92.1911593, 42.8689561, 18.5230607, 23.0842770, 132.5477074, 50.2996339, 3.1371337, NaN,NaN)
 VelocityData <- data.frame(stepheights = stepheights, Qs = Qs)

#create our graphing parameters using ggplot
 downstream_QS<-ggplot(data=VelocityData, aes(x=stepheights, y=Qs)) + geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y ~ log(x), fill="red") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=stepheights) +
  labs(x="Distance Downstream (cm)", y="Sediment Transport") +
  ggtitle("Sediment Transport Downstream of a Backward-Facing Step as Calculated from Near-bed Shear Stress") + 
  theme(plot.title=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", size=24), 
        axis.title.y=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", 
                              size=14),      axis.title.x=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", size=14),
    axis.text.y=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", size=10),
    axis.text.x=element_text(family="Palatino", face="bold", size=10))

 # Original method of saving
 pdf(paste('ADV Qs Profile.pdf'), width=8, height=4)
 print(downstream_QS)
 dev.off()

# or you can use ggsave - I've changed the sizes to get the titles to fit
 ggsave('ADV Qs Profile2.pdf',downstream_QS, width=18, height=14, units="in")
```